# Use local time in query

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I want my results from this query to show with local time not the UTC:

```
union * 
|  
order by timestamp desc
```

How would I go about getting that to show local time?  I know it is some variation on `dateadd(timestamp - 7h)` but I can't figure out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since all datetimes are expressed in UTC, it is often useful to convert these into our local timezone. For simply viewing data, we can **add a column using datetime math to add or subtract the necessary number of hours**. You could refer to this [article](https://docs.loganalytics.io/docs/Learn/Tutorials/Date-and-time-operations) for more details.

```
union * 
| extend localTimestamp = timestamp - 7h
| order by localTimestamp desc
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There is also now the ability through the UI settings to default all reports to local time, this helps when you have to account for daylight savings.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question exactly, but it's my preferred solution

Comment: This is my preferred solution as well. thank you!